# Problem with "Edit and Continue" in a ASP.NET core mixed Razor Pages and MVC app

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages, edit-and-continue

I'm trying to update an old webpage that I had developed using MVC. Now I'm adding Razor Pages, but then Edit and Continue won't work anymore.
I can isolate/reproduce the problem in a minimal context. It seems to occur when there are files both in Pages and in Views, e.g. _ViewStart.cshtml.
Here is how to reproduce:

- Create an ASP.NET Core Web App, .NET 5.0, No Authentication, no HTTPs, no Docker, enable Razor runtime compilation
- Place a breakpoint in IndexModel constructor
- Run App
- When hitting the breakpoint, edit the code (just add a semicolon in the ctor), continue: code will compile and continue
- Add new folder "Views"
- Copy _ViewStart.cshtml from Pages to Views
- Run App again
- When hitting the breakpoint, edit the code (just add a semicolon in the ctor), continue, get message: "Edits were made to the code which cannot be applied while debugging"

I could probably work around the issue, but I'd rather try to understand why this happens.
This also happens when I add the Identity package and try to customize the pages, in which case I also need a double _ViewStart.cshtml...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you edit the code while debugging?

Comment: Because when I find errors during debugging, it's easier and faster to modify the code and continue than to restart the app. Isn't that what Edit and Continue is for?